# Does Elan apply to non-combat Trait tests?

Tags: savage-worlds

The Elan edga gives a +2 bonus on any trait rolls made when spending a Benny.  However, Elan is a Combat Edge.  Does this +2 bonus apply to rolls made outside of combat?  If so, what makes this a combat edge?

For example: If I'm making a Persuasion roll to get some help from an Uncooperative NPC, can I get a +2 by spending a Benny if I have Elan?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes it does. Elan can be used with any Trait test which is rerolled with a Bennie. See [this question on the official forum](http://www.peginc.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=45828&highlight=elan) for confirmation.

> If an Edge type has any limitations on its use, it's noted under the overall description. Combat Edges just fall into a category that aid a character in dishing out damage or surviving it. If the Edge can affect other uses too, that's just a bonus.
>
> So it applies to any reroll made with a Benny, in or out of combat.

When all else fails, turn to the official source!